# Ignore excel formula is the cell is not blank and change the color of cell when the formula is applied

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

i want to write a formula in excel where it ignores the formula if the cell is not blank.

[image: pic]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQ6rK.png)

In `Jan '#P'` column which is `C11`, we have numbers like 2,5,1 and some blank cells. I want to insert the below mentioned formula.

```
=(IF(C11=1,10%,IF(C11=2,20%,IF(C11=3,25%,IF(C11=4,30%,IF(C11=5,40%,IF(C11=6,50%,IF(C11=7,60%,IF(C11=8,70%,IF(C11=9,80%))))))))))
```

I want the formula to work only if the cells in column 'D11' which is `%U` is blank,

1) if D11 is blank, apply the formula that uses C11

2) If D11 is already present , ignore the formula.

I am also wondering if we change the color of the cell using formula. I want the cells to be highlighted in blue color while applying the above formula.

Any help please?

[image: pi]

Comment: search for "conditional formatting"

Comment: You are looking to overwrite only empty cells with a formula? I doubt this can be done without the use of VBA.

Answer (score 0):

```
=if(D11="",(IF(C11=1,10%,IF(C11=2,20%,IF(C11=3,25%,IF(C11=4,30%,IF(C11=5,40%,IF(C11=6,50%,IF(C11=7,60%,IF(C11=8,70%,IF(C11=9,80%)))))))))),"")
```

you cant highlight cell using formula. you can use conditional formatting.

Comment: this returns 0. ** =IF(D10="",(IF(C10=1,10%,IF(C10=2,20%,IF(C10=3,25%,IF(C10=4,30%,IF(C10=5,40%,IF(C10=6,50%,IF(C10=7,60%,IF(C10=8,70%,IF(C10=9,80%)))))))))),"") **

Comment: Add more big screenshot where I can see column letters and row numbers.

Comment: are you trying to enter this formula in D10 and check if D10 is blank or not? it is impossible

Comment: Yeah D10 is blank at first, so it must fill 10%. But it fills 0.0% . When i dragged the formula down, it fills 0.0% for non-blank cell too

Comment: As I told you, you cant check D10 if you are entering this formal in D10. yes, it will return 0 because refers to itself.

Comment: How can i proceed then?

Comment: you cant with standard excel formulas. use VBA sub procedures.